# How to install libcurl libs for aarch64 in unbutu

Tags: ubuntu, libcurl, arm64

When I try to compile using `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`, I'm getting the following error:

`ld returned q exit status... aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc/bin.ld: cannot find -lcurl`

libcurl libs are already installed (`apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`). But still seeing this error.
How can I install the libcurl bins for aarch64?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you try passing the path using the '-L' option?

Comment: In my experience it starts with "fight with `dpkg --add-architecture` with increasing frustration" and ends with "build everything from source by hand".